# IntegrityError with last_login field in Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.8

I have a project deployed to a server with Django 1.8 where the creation of a new user results in this error:

> null value in column "last_login" violates not-null constraint

This seems to be caused by [a known bug](https://github.com/fusionbox/django-authtools/issues/33) that was addressed some months back.

What do I need to do to get the fix? Or should this issue be dealt with in some other way?

Comment: Reinstall your package if they have released it and then you're good to go.

Answer (score 9):

I just had to create a new migration for my app:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations
$ ./manage.py migrate
```